# How can i access a HashMap with JSTL-EL in a jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

Hi all
I have a problem with accessing an HashMap into my jsl using EL and JSTL
my hashmap is like so in the servlet:

```
HashMap indexes=new HashMap();
```

then lets suppose i add somthing like:

```
indexes.put(1,"Erik")
```

then i add it to the session:`session.setAttribute("indexes",indexes)`

from the jsp if i access the hashmap like this

```
${sessionScope.indexes}
```

it shows all key-value pair in the map, but like this for example:

```
${sessionScope.indexes[1]} or ${sessionScope.indexes['1']}
```

it wont work

as far as i can see this is the ethod used in many tutorials i dont know where i'm failing
any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers are treated as Long in EL. In your case:

```
HashMap indexes = new HashMap();
indexes.put(1, "Erik"); // here it autobox 1 to Integer
```

and on jsp

```
${sessionScope.indexes[1]} // will search for Long 1 in map as key so it will return null
${sessionScope.indexes['1']} // will search for String 1 in map as key so it will return null
```

So either you can make your map key is a Long or String to use .

```
Map<Long, String> indexes = new HashMap<Long, String>();
indexes.put(1L, "Erik"); // here it autobox 1 to Long
```

and

```
${sessionScope.indexes[1]} // will look for Long 1 in map as key
```

or

```
Map<String, String> indexes = new HashMap<String, String>();
indexes.put("1", "Erik");
```

and

```
${sessionScope.indexes['1']} // will look for String 1 in map as key
```